# What are the best camera setting to take a sunrise?

Tags: sun

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you make the most stunning sun rise/set photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4870/how-do-you-make-the-most-stunning-sun-rise-set-photos)

I want to take a picture of a sunrise, and want to see the outline of the sun clearly. What focus and exposure would you recommend? (as I am new to this, I would appreciate a bit more info)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that is not possible. The sun is so much brighter than anything else in the picture, so if you expose as to avoid getting the sun too overexposed, the rest of the image will be very dark, or even completely black.

You have a bigger chance to do that with a sunset. The particles that fills the air during the day will filter out a lot of the sunlight, which also turns it into the characteristic red colour. In the morning there is much less particles in the air to filter the sunlight.