# What are the best spots around Louisville, KY to shoot wildlife?

Tags: wildlife, birds, locations

Just as the title says, does anyone know any good wildlife spots around Louisville, KY? I am interested in birds, small critters, but also larger animals.

Comment: You might find some ideas from this question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4418/how-should-i-go-about-finding-awesome-locations-for-landscape-shots

Comment: Meta discussion here: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/63/photo-location-tips-on-or-off-topic/. Personally, I'm not really buying that these are _too_ localized. This is a city with ³⁄₄ million people, and yes, millions of tourists. They've got the Kentucky Derby, and, hey, _bourbon_. That doesn't fit the "too localized" example of "why is that car parked outside my house". There might be problems with subjectivity ("good" spots, "best" subjects), and with open-endedness, but that's a different issue.

Comment: After reading Joel's point http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/what-questions-should-be-closed-with-reason-too-localized/87415#87415 about too localized and some convincing logic from @mattdm - I'd rescind my close vote if I could, at least in regards to it being too localized.

Comment: I have to agree with @mattdm here as well. I think this is one of those areas where PhotoSE sets itself apart from the more technical side of SE, and questions like this can be useful to viewers in the future.

Comment: That said, I've never been to Louisville, so _I_ can't answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I love going to Papa John's Park over off of Bluegrass Parkway. If you're able to travel and getting up early, you can go to Birnhim just south of Louisville near bardstown. They have some awesome woods and trees.

May sound silly, but when I got into photography several years ago, I got a season pass to the Louisville Zoo and had some awesome learning experience and amazing photos.

Just across the bridge, you can check out Falls of the Ohio and get some awesome water shots.

Over by riverfront, there's a water park that has sprinklers that makes for neat photos.

If you have a dog and member of a Louisville Dog park, you can go and get some cool pictures of dogs running.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions! Having trouble finding the Papa john's Park and Birhim as I'm not a local, and this is only my second visit to the US. Any chance you could point these two places out on Google Maps for example? Thank you again!

Comment: Also, the Louisville Zoo was great! I'm only here for 3 more weeks so I'm not getting a season pass, but the place i work at has a $3 discount for the admission.

Comment: Papa Johns Park is off of I64 and the Blankenbaker exit. If you get off of there and head southbound, you'll see a McDonalds on your right. You'll want to make a left at that light and then travel about 1/4-1/2 mile. You'll see the rocky water fall and ponds off to your right. It's really awesome for night time long exposure shots. You get some really neat shots of the water.